# Angular 2 Parent afterViewInit fired before Child afterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, lifecycle

I have a parent container and a child component.

Child components are variable in number and are fetched off XHR request.

Parent Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
     <child *ngFor="let c of children" [c]="c"></child>
   `
})
export default class ParentContainer implements AfterViewInit {
children: C[];

constructor(public api: Api) {
this.api.getC().subscribe(res => this.children = res);

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('parent afterNgView');
}
```

Child Component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'child',
template: `      
   <div>Child</div>
`
})
export default class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@Input() c: C;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('child afterViewInit');
}
```

When I execute this I see `parent afterNgView` appear before all the `child afterNgView` logs. I was expecting the children ngAfterViewInit to execute first.

There must be a way to ensure all children are done loading before a parent handler is invoked. I looked through NG2 LifeCycle Hooks assuming the parent AfterViewInit would only get called after the children. That's not the case.

How can I get the children to inform the parent they are finished? There should be something out the box ... ?

This is a screenshot from NG2 LifeCycle Hooks guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

[image]

This is what I'm doing until I find something cleaner:

Parent Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
     <child *ngFor="let c of children" [c]="c" (childIsLoaded)="childIsLoaded($event)"></child>
   `
})
export default class ParentContainer implements AfterViewInit {
children: C[];

constructor(public api: Api) {
this.api.getC().subscribe(res => this.children = res);

childIsLoaded() {
  console.log('Child\'s ngAfterViewInit Complete !!');    
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('parent afterNgView');
}
```

Child Component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'child',
template: `      
   <div>Child</div>
`
})
export default class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@Input() c: C;
@Output() childIsLoaded = new EventEmitter<any>();

ngAfterViewInit() {
  ...init code...
  this.childIsLoaded.emit();
}
```

In the above snippet, the child emits an event notifying the parent that its ngAfterViewInit fired. There must be something out of the box that does this for me ? Instead of me re-writing this child-notify-parent scheme for all my nested components .. ?

Comment: `AfterViewInit` is only init not `Crration Complete` check `AfterViewChecked`

Comment: According to the Angular 2 life cycle hooks, Parent will always load first and then the children by their load priorities. You can't get child to be load first.

Comment: You're loading data asynchronously.

Comment: @Krunai see the edited post - there's a screenshot of the LifeCycle hooks documentation

Comment: @yurzui thanks for stating the obvious

Comment: At first time there are no child elements. Why do you expect running `child afterViewInit` while your template is empty?

Comment: What about using `setTimeout(...)` in the parent `afterViewInit()`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you mean guessing some delay? that's a non-deterministic hack - I want to know precisely when the child has completed render, not guess using a timer -

Comment: I don't talk about guessing some delay. I assume the components are created sync and if the code in the parent is scheduled to run after the current task is completed, then it should run after the child. Just don't specify a timeout duration.